# Storing file on a specific path after scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

i want to store my file into a folder after scraping data and i didn't know how to add exactly to my script :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/chrome/chromedriver.exe")
driver.execute("get", {'url': 'http://www.ins.tn/statistiques/90#'})
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='export']//a[@class='btnexport  ' and starts-with(@id, 'btnExporttoExcel')]"))).click()
```

This is the path of the foler : `C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\data`

Also, how to change the name of the file ecerytime i scrape data ? like adding the time of the last time that i excuted the code !

Answer (score 0):

Selenium has an obtions object in the `webdriver` module that you can modify and pass to the driver when instantiating the driver.

For chrome, I set up the options object in a method like this, so I can just pass in my path to `dest` and get the modified object.

```py
    def change_download_folder(dest):
        options = selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        prefs = {}
        os.makedirs(dest, exist_ok=True)
        prefs["profile.default_content_settings.popups"] = 0
        prefs["download.default_directory"] = dest
        options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
        return options
```

Then you can call this and pass the return to the driver instantiation:

```py
options = change_download_folder("YOUR_FILE_PATH")
driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(
            options = options,
            executable_path = "PATH_TO_DRIVER_FILE"
            )
```